# Installing ubuntu on a completely fresh Dell Latitude 7490

Tags: uefi, dell

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a Latitude 7490, but UEFI is really messing me up.

It says no bootable media found. It will not pick up my USB stick if "Enable Lagacy Option Roms" is not checked. If that is checked, then it installs ubuntu and says no bootable media is found. It used to be so easy.

Comment: No idea if your PC supports it, but most have settings in the UEFI interface that allow turning on a "Compatibility Support Mode" that allows you to do an old-style install.

Answer (score 0):

Was very confusing, and lucky I was able to, but I needed to burn the Ubuntu image with Rufus (in UEFI compatibility mode) on Windows.

Comment: Hi @DaraJava does the model fully work with Ubuntu including it's touchscreen?